# Why changing the database owner doesn't change the owner in PostgreSQL dump?

Tags: postgresql

I was exporting a database using `pg_dump` command when I realized that the owner of the database had to be changed. So I change it, and make extra sure that the `newuser` is correct. Then try the command again:

```
pg_dump -h localhost -U postgres database_name -f mydb.dump
```

But this didn't work. The output file still identified the owner as the `olduser`. Why could this be happening? How can I make sure this doesn't happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you are invoking `pg_dump` (without `-C`), the database metadata is not dumped at all.

Use this:

```
pg_dump -h localhost -U postgres database_name -C -f mydb.dump
```

This will add `CREATE DATABASE` and `ALTER DATABASE ... OWNER TO` to your dump.